# uploading video generates warning even when the conditions is not met

Tags: php

I am trying to upload videos of a user in the same directory, this is my code.

```
$folder = 'data/videos/'.$fields['agenda_id']."_".str_replace(' ', '_', 
$fields['agenda_title']) . " /user_".$fields['user_id']."/";

if (!file_exists($folder)) 
{
mkdir('data/videos/'.$fields['agenda_id']."_".str_replace(' ', '_', $fields['agenda_title']) .'/user_'.$fields['user_id'], 0777, true);    
}
```

It works fine for the first time, but when the user tries to upload the second video it generates this error.

A PHP Error was encountered

```
<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  mkdir(): File exists</p>
<p>Filename: restful/Api.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 641</p>
<p>Backtrace:</p>
```

I am just unable to get, why it is going in if condition even when it is false

Comment: You should use `$folder` variable in `mkdir` function because it is the same path unless you have a typo in there.

Comment: After the first time the folder is created can you check it's owner and it's rights? Maybe some other process is changing them.

Answer (score 0):

`file_exists`

Warning - This function returns FALSE for files inaccessible due to safe mode restrictions. However these files still can be included if they are located in safe_mode_include_dir.

Note: The results of this function are cached. See clearstatcache() for more details.

Comment: Then how come it is working properly the first time ??
This issue occurs when the user tries to upload video the second time.

Comment: The first time the folder doesn't exist. The second time your folder exists and the function still returns false.

Comment: so where should I actually use clearstatcache() . befor if condition; in if condition or after if condition?

Comment: before the condition

Comment: After your suggestion i updated my code like this, but still same error.


clearstatcache();
$folder = 'data/videos/'.$fields['agenda_id']."_".str_replace(' ', '_', $fields['agenda_title']) . " /user_".$fields['user_id']."/";
        if (!file_exists($folder)) {
            mkdir('data/videos/'.$fields['agenda_id']."_".str_replace(' ', '_', $fields['agenda_title']) .'/user_'.$fields['user_id'], 0777, true);
        }

Comment: Do a `ls -la`. What are your folder permissions?

Comment: permission is 0755